# Program that can count deficient numbers

Tags: counting

Using Mathematica, I want to make program which can solve the following question.

> What is the number of [deficient numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deficient_number) less than 100?

Please help me.

Answer (score 8):

```
Count[ILD`DeficientNumberQ /@ Range[100], True]
```

> 76

Alternatively, you can use [`DivisorSigma[1, n]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DivisorSigma.html) or  [`DivisorSum[n, Identity]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DivisorSum.html) to get the sum of divisors of `n`:

```
DivisorSigma[1, Range @ 1000] == DivisorSum[Range @ 1000, Identity]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

We can use either with `Count`:

```
Count[Thread[DivisorSigma[1, Range@100] < 2 Range[100]], True]
```

> ```
>  76
> ```

```
Count[Thread[DivisorSum[ Range@100, Identity] < 2 Range[100]], True]
```

> ```
>  76
> ```

To get the list of deficient numbers in `Range[n]` you can use

```
n = 50;
Select[ILD`DeficientNumberQ] @ Range[n]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19, 21, 22, 23, 
>  25, 26, 27, 29, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 39, 41, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 49, 50}
> ```

```
Select[DivisorSigma[1, #] < 2 # &]@Range[n]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19, 21, 22, 23, 
>  25, 26, 27, 29, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 39, 41, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 49, 50}
> ```

```
Select[DivisorSum[#, Identity] < 2 # &]@Range[n]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19, 21, 22, 23, 
>  25, 26, 27, 29, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 39, 41, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 49, 50}
> ```

```
% == %%
```

> True

Comment: Very nice.  "Count[Array[ILD`DeficientNumberQ,100],True]" also seems to work.  (Another Mathematica function I knew nothing about)

Answer (score 7):

From [`Wikipedia`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deficient_number)

> In number theory, a deficient number or defective number is a number n
>   for which the sum of divisors σ(n)<2n

Therefore

```
If[Total[Divisors[#]] < 2 #, #, Nothing[]] & /@ Range[100]
```

gives

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19, 21, 22, 23, \
25, 26, 27, 29, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 39, 41, 43, 44, 45, 46, \
47, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 55, 57, 58, 59, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 67, 68, \
69, 71, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 79, 81, 82, 83, 85, 86, 87, 89, 91, 92, \
93, 94, 95, 97, 98, 99}
```

Answer (score 4):

With some serious 'borrowing' from other answers:

```
Array[2# > DivisorSum[#, Identity]&, 100] //Counts
```

> ```
> <|True -> 76, False -> 24|>
> ```

**Original Answer**

```
Count[Array[2#-Total[Divisors[#]]&, 100]//Clip,1]
```

> 76

```
Array[{#,2#-Total[Divisors[#]]}&, 100]//Pick[#[[All,1]],#[[All,2]]//Clip,1]&
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19, 21, 22, 23, 25, 26, 27, 29, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 39, 41, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 55, 57, 58, 59, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 67, 68, 69, 71, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 79, 81, 82, 83, 85, 86, 87, 89, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 97, 98, 99}

```
%//Length
```

> 76

Comment: But `Array[ILD\`DeficientNumberQ, 100] // Counts` (as a slight variant of that given by kglr) is probably superior to anything given above.